# Batch Convert Files Different Output Folder

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Goal is to convert all .wav files to .mp3 in a different location.
The following code works, but creates output files in the same directory.
All the newly created .mp3's are right alongside the .wav's.

```
for file in /path/to/*.wav; do lame --preset insane "$file" "${file%.wav}".mp3; done
```

How can I use terminal to convert a drive full of .wav's with lame and output the .mp3's to a different drive? I've tried changing lame's output, but this syntax grabs the entire filename. Looking for the most simple solution.

From the lame manual, the synopsis is very straightforward:

```
lame [options] <infile> <outfile>
```

Found the basic concept [here](https://manuelbaumann.com/2016/12/batch-convert-wav-files-to-mp3-in-osx-using-terminal/)

Comment: Easiest is to just `cd` to the desired output directory before running `lame`. You likely can do `"/path_to_folder/${file%.wav}".mp3;` as the output argument to `lame`. You also have `/path/to/` as part of you glob so that same path will be part of the output argument...

Comment: Almost got it, getting a "Can't init outfile" but seems to be pointing to the right destination!  Used `cd` to desired output directory, then running `for file in **/*.wav; do lame --preset insane "$file" "/Volumes/MUSICA/${file%.wav}".mp3; done`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the output files should be placed to /output, possible to extend loop to calculate the output file name using the 'basename'

```
OUT=/output
for file in /path/to/*.wav; do
    # Replace .wav with .mp3
    out=${file%.wav}.mp3
    # Remove directory (anything up to the last '/'
    out=${file##*/}
    lame --preset insane "$file" $OUT/$out
done
```

Comment: Still not working, getting "Can't init outfile". How is the directory from the path being removed in that step? I want to specify an entirely different path for output files such as /Volumes/disk1. Thanks for your help, almost got it.

Comment: @RyanvonSchwedler answer fixed to place output in whatever OUT will be set to.